# Calling a method in a separate function does not update the object attribute

Tags: javascript

I am studying javascript and I have a question about updating an object attribute through a separate function. My call "Email" has an attribute hasBeenRead = false and a method markAsRead() which changes false to True. I have created an array in which all new emails entered by a user are pushed and I need to create a separate function that will print out a specific message and update hasBeenRead to true. I am stuck on the second part. I call the method markAsRead but this doesn't update the attribute.

```
class Email{ 
    count = 1;

    constructor(fromAddress, emailContents){
        this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
        this.emailContents = emailContents;
        this.hasBeenRead = false;
        this.isSpam = false;
    }
    
    markAsRead(){
        this.hasBeenRead = true;
    }

    markAsSpam(){
        this.isSpam = true;
    }
}
```

and here is my function:

```
let userIndex;

function getEmail(array, userIndex){

    userIndex = Number(prompt("Please enter the number of the email you would like to see: "));
    let index = userIndex - 1; 
    emailRead = array[index]

    if (index < array.length){  
        let msg = emailRead.emailContents
        console.log(`Your email says ${msg}.`)
        emailRead.markAsRead()
    }   

    else {
        console.log(`There is no message ${userIndex} in your inbox.`)
    }
}

getEmail(inbox, userIndex)
console.log(inbox)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: This should work just fine. What makes you assume that `hasBeenRead` is not updated?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including the definition of `inbox`

Comment: After testing it myself, it looks like it's working as you expect it to. hasBeenRead is updating.

Comment: Btw, `userIndex` should be a local variable inside the  `getEmail` function, just like `index` is. It should neither be a global variable nor a parameter of the function. Also the `emailRead` variable is missing a declaration.

Comment: In addition to what @Bergi mentioned. You should check for indices being 0 or smaller in your `ìf` statement as a user might supply 0 or smaller numbers. Also you should use integers e.g. using `parseInt()` otherwise a user might supply `1.2` as an index which will also result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Well, the hasBeenRead updates in the function (I can see that when I console.log array[index] within the function - hasBeenRead has changed to true for the relevant instance) but when I call my function and then console.log my array, I can see that hasBeenRead is still false.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a declaration for emailRead and I declared userIndex outside the function because I am using it as an argument when I call the function. I thought that was necessary.

Comment: @user20963972 No, `hasBeenRead` is `true` after calling `markAsRead()`. See https://jsfiddle.net/f5bqyp4d/

Comment: Ok, I will submit as it is then. Thank you all for your help.